# Android: CertPathValidatorException - TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed

Tags: android, ssl, bouncycastle

I am trying to authenticate my android application over a https connection to the server.

I a getting the following exception while trying to authenticate. While looked up for solution, there were lots of suggestions about binding certificate with apk, ignoring the certificate validation etc.

[Detailed StackTrace](http://hastebin.com/mocodafaca.avrasm)

The problem is, in few phones and emulators this authentication over https works perfectly fine. And in my phone as well as in my emulator it doesn't go through. So looks like its more of a device issue than code one.

Has anyone else have faced this kind of issue and sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

The error meaning is: the SSL certificate chain (from the server certificate to a trust anchor in the Root CA store) has been rebuild by the application but the validation of this chain failed for any reason.

In the stacktrace the underlying error is `java.security.NoSuchProviderException: AndroidOpenSSL`. It means that the application tries to instantiate a signature validation object with a cryptographic provider which is not present in the android system. This error makes me thinking that it may be an android version issue.

Can you tell us the target API level used to build your application? And what are the versions of the terminals on which the application works and does not work?

Comment: Thanks. Our minSDK is 8 and targetSDK is 17. The apk compiled in a local box works in one emulator but not in other. So looks like some RunTimeEnvironment issue. It will be helpful to know what to look out for in the emulators/device. Both the emulator runs 4.3 (API 17)

Comment: Hi Jcs, I am interested in the above explanation.  Now i met a ssl exception issue but i don't know what can be the root cause. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438993/android-https-ssl-hand-shake-exception

But that exception occurs random only after the service is stopped and restarted again. 

The exception is TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed. I would like to know how is rebuild by the application and cause the certificate validation failed.

Comment: In happened scenario: I have some services that will do all the background tasks including https request.  But when user logout, these  services will be stopped. But the application still alive with login UI. when user login again which needs to do https request, in some timing, the issue occured. In this case, the application have to restarted and then all will be fined again. So i doubt about this is caused by stopping the services and then something changes cause this issue. But have no  idea how to solve it. If you have some suggestion, please let me know. Thanks a lot.