# android https CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed

Tags: android, https, okhttp

Does anyone meet the below exception.

It occurs random. After it happened, then https connection cannot be used anymore. The whole application needs to restart.

The scenario :
After detailed trace of the code, i updated the scenario:

```
1. The application has 3 process in the same application.
2. The main ui process invoke https request in another thread.
3. The another 2 processes hold the 2 servcies. one service will also invoke https request in another thread.
4. When user logout, it will stop the 2 services.
3. When user login again, the main ui process invoke https request and then fail.
```

The code is like below:

```
URL url = new URL(mUri);
urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod(mMethod);
if (mMethod.equals(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME)) {
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
}
else {
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
}
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
...
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mJsonContent)) {
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(mJsonContent);
    wr.close();
}
//Get Response
InputStream inputStream;
int statusCode;
statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
...
inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
String bodyContent = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
inputStream.close();

if (urlConnection != null) {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

I would like to know what can be the root cause. Currenlty i have no clue to solve this error. The https connection is run in another thread. After getting response, it will post back to main thread.

```
W/System.err( 7158): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:409)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.xxxx.xxx.util.http.AsyncHttpsClient$AsyncRequest.run(AsyncHttpsClient.java:304)

W/System.err( 7158):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

W/System.err( 7158):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

W/System.err( 7158):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

W/System.err( 7158): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:308)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:611)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)

W/System.err( 7158):    ... 13 more

W/System.err( 7158): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:122)

W/System.err( 7158):    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:190)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:295)

W/System.err( 7158):    ... 17 more

W/System.err( 7158): Caused by: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.AnnotatedException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.findTrustAnchor(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:235)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:117)

W/System.err( 7158):    ... 19 more

W/System.err( 7158): Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.X509_verify(Native Method)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.verifyOpenSSL(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:334)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.verify(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:367)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.verifyX509Certificate(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:1427)

W/System.err( 7158):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.findTrustAnchor(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:222)

W/System.err( 7158):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Does it happen on all devices or only an specific devices or Android versions?

Comment: It currently happened on Nexus 5 4.4.4 more easily.

Answer (score 0):

According to other sources like [[1](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7016299),[2](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/forum/error-message-curl-error-error-0d0890a1-asn1-encoding-routines-asn1_verify-unknown-message-digest-algorithm)] you have probably outdated OpenSSL version. Try updating your openSSL version. Minimal version: OpenSSL 0.9.8o

Your BouncyCastle uses OpenSSL `com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.verify` to verify the certificate.

The exception `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm` means the certificate uses digest that is not handled in the OpenSSL, most probably SHA256.

UPDATE 01:
As noted in comments, in Android you cannot update system OpenSSL. 
Lets experiment:

- Try visit domain with your code (if possible) which uses SHA-256 certificate (works in 100% cases or not):
  https://www.fi.muni.cz/
- Then you can try to discover more details about your client support here:
  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html
- Then more info about your server (ciphersuites, notice digests):
  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

What are your Android and OKHttp versions? Your system uses https://conscrypt.org/ as a crypto provider. You can try to avoid using system bundled OpenSSL & BouncyCastle versions by using a new version of BouncyCastle - SpongyCastle.

Follow instructions here https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/ to install SpongyCastle as a new and preferred crypto provider (`core`, `prov`, `pkix`). If SpongyCastle is in effect your stacktrace will contain spongycastle packages.

Comment: Usually OpenSSL is part of the Android OS and can not be updated separately.

Comment: I use the android okhttp, i think it is not possible to update the openssl of the device. The only way is i use not okhttp? 

But it is not 100% occured in the device. It is ok at first. It happen sometimes after logout and then back to login again. I would like to know which lead to the way this issue happen? 

Is it the problem that server and client handshake, server select different digest that cause the issue? Sometimes server select digest that support in client side and sometimes select not support in client side to handshake?

Comment: My device is android 4.4.4 and android 5.0.2. I used the device google chrome to viewMyClient.html. It supported SHA256 like below. I also tested the server. I post it in another answer, because there are lots to mention. Thanks a lot for taking a look.

Comment: Well thats weird. What about spongy castle? have you tried?

Comment: Have you seen my another post in answer? How do you think for the 2 certification paths? I haven't try the spongy castle.